# How to access CONSTANT value from different js file in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, constants

**constants.js** file below

```
'use strict'

angular.module('app').constant('CONSTANT' { 
    "myValues": {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "car": "ford suv"
     }
```

I would like to simply access  "myValues" from

**ang-extention.js** file and simply use it like:

```
function getMyStuff() {
    console.log(CONSTANT.myValues.fruit);
}
```

I tried:

```
angular.module(['CONSTANT', function(CONSTANT) {
    console.log(CONSTANT.myValues.fruit');
}]);
```

but no luck. How is it done in this case? 
I searched various terms for example, "how to use constants in angularJS" I read bunch of answers but i didn't understand them so far and ended up asking SO myself.
 Thank you so much in advance..

Comment: angular.module requires the name of the module to create/use... There is no function to provide. In `angular.module('myModule').run(function(CONSTANT) { });` it will work.

Comment: Please ignore } missing in constants.js in the question. I forgot..

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanks, is ('myModule') -> can this be any name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the constant, simply inject it into the `.run` function:

```
angular.module("app").run(function(CONSTANT) {
    console.log(CONSTANT.myValues.fruit);
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)